# Why is my firestore data 'useruid' and not the actual uid?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Just a really simple question for cloud functions. I am just wondering why is the data in my firestore (in the simulator) appears to be:

```
useruid 
  Item Name:        "Yummy Food"
  Item Price:       "25"
  Item Quantity:    "50"
```

and not what I wanted which is:

```
qwjeqjwioej123123123
  Item Name:        "Yummy Food"
  Item Price:       "25"
  Item Quantity:    "50"
```

The below is my code:

```
exports.addCurrentOrder = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const useruid = req.query.uid;
  const itemName = req.query.itemName;
  const itemPrice = req.query.itemPrice;
  const itemQuantity = req.query.itemQuantity;
  console.log('This is in useruid: ', useruid);

  const data = { useruid : {
     'Item Name': itemName,
     'Item Price': itemPrice,
     'Item Quantity': itemQuantity,
  }};

  const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('Current Orders}').add(data);
  res.json({result: data});
});
```

Sorry I dont have much JS expereince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is indeed literally putting that string into the document as the name of the field.  That's how JavaScript objects work.

If you want to substitute the value of a variable as the name of an object property, you can use square bracket syntax to provide express that evaluates to the string to use:

```
  const data = { [useruid] : {
     'Item Name': itemName,
     'Item Price': itemPrice,
     'Item Quantity': itemQuantity,
  }};
```

Comment: That was quick and easy! Thanks Doug!